# when I get a trick and apply that on my work, should I say "put it in" or "put it on"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

when I get a trick (a new way, thanks to @wavery), say, an operation that can make my PPT(PowerPoint) more impressive, I would apply that on my work.

should I say "put it in" or "put it on" ?

Answer (score 0):

From a very basic level understanding of your question, I would say "Put it in your Powerpoint" and not "Put it on your Powerpoint", assuming that is what you are asking.

Also what do you mean by a "trick"? I think you are trying to say a new discovery or a new way to do something, but "trick" sounds like you are trying to play a joke on someone.

Feel free to let me know if I have misunderstood you.

Comment: "trick" is often used for "method of doing something" as in "you need to learn the trick of saving documents under a new name" or 'I found the trick for reducing fractions" or "a shooter must master the trick of squeezing the trigger"

Comment: @David I agree with what you are saying.  think I think what threw me off was the way it was said: "when I get a trick and apply that on my work". Maybe that was some sort of English translation issue that the site is trying to do?

Comment: To the best of my understanding the site deosn't do any automatic translation, instead, any translation is done by individual posters. I would say that "apply that on my work" is a somewhat unnatural phrase as used here -- "in my work" or "to my work" would be more usual".